# how to update an array in array of objects

Tags: ruby

I have following output available in a variable test

```
#<someobject customer=[#<someobject product=[#<someobject id='ABC123'>, #<someobject id=''>], id='ADE343'>]>
```

I am trying to convert its result as follows:

```
#<someobject customer=[#<someobject product=['ABC123','DEF143'], id='ADE343'>]>
```

I can achieve that using following but looks like overkill

```
test1 = test.customer.map { |p| p.product }.flatten.map { |e| e.id }
test.customer.map { |p| p.product = test1 }
test
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: is this rails or just ruby?  before `customer.product` returned an array of product objects I think but now you want it to return an array of strings?

Comment: Can you show the associated class definition (with `initialize` the only method), in part so we can test?

Answer (score 2):

```
test.customer.tap { |obj| obj.product.map!(&:id) }
```